# Disable playing audio when locked

Tags: windows-10, security, privacy, lock-screen

If I'm playing a video (for example on YouTube) and put my computer in sleep mode, when it wakes up, it will keep playing audio and display the video title in the corner despite it being locked and not signed in.

How can I disable this? I don't want any information to be available before I sign in.

Answer (score 1):

*You will need:

 1. [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to trigger the functionality when you lock the computer

 2. A new task in Windows' Task Scheduler.*

The first thing you may want to do is download and extract NirCmd on the system. You do not need to do anything else with it, just remember the path it is located on as we need that later on.

Open the Windows Task Scheduler next. You can do so by loading a run box with Windows-r, typing taskschd.msc and hitting the enter key.

Or use the search functionality of your operating system and search for Task Scheduler which should also work just fine.

Select Create Task from the actions menu on the right.

Add a name and if you want a description for the task on the general tab that opens up.
[image]
Switch to the triggers tab next. Here you need to create two triggers, as you want to mute the sound when you lock the workstation, and unmute it when you unlock it again.

If you only want it muted automatically, you only need to create a single trigger here.

Select new and select on workstation lock and for the next trigger on workstation unlock and leave every other setting as is.
[image]
Switch to the actions tab afterwards and click on the new button here. Keep start a program as the action, and browse to the nircmd.exe script on the PC's hard drive.

Add mutesysvolume 2 as the argument and click on ok afterwards.
[image]
The command toggles between mute and unmute state of the sound on the system. You find additional examples on the Nirsoft website. The command nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1  will mute the volume for instance but not unmute it at a later point in time.

NirCmd is compatible with all supported versions of the Microsoft Windows operating system.

### To disable notifications:

**Settings > System > Notifications & Actions**
set "Show notifications on lock screen" and "Show alarms, reminders, and incoming VOIP calls on the lock screen" to OFF

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Someone can still unmute the sound when on the lock screen, and the notification that shows the video title is still there.